# How to install ubuntu 20.10 on macbook air 2017

Tags: linux, ubuntu, macintosh

So I tried to install ubuntu on my macbook air 13" 2017 model yesterday. I had wiped my harddrive clean to install ubuntu 20.10 as the sole OS on my laptop. I burnt an ubuntu image onto my flashdrive and booted into it after holding the option key. I chose the default installation settings and the Installation went fine. However I can only boot into ubuntu once after installation. When I restart, I am met with an ubuntu loading screen with a spinning wheel... It's definitely stuck in some sort of bootloop. I don't know how to fix this and I've tried searching everywhere online. Would really appreciate your help!

Edit: I forgot to mention I get the "failed to set moklistrt:invalid paramater" error.

Comment: Do not know Mac, but have seen some say you have to dual boot as you need the Mac operating system to update it. rEFInd on newer MAC with Secure Boot
https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/1a96f5bd6d/?limit=25 With An Out-Of-Tree Kernel Patch You Can Finally Read/Write To The SSDs On Newer Macs - 2019 July
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MacBook-Finally-Linux-SSD-RW Upgrade Mac
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886
Linux on mid-2017 MacBookPro
https://nixaid.com/linux-on-macbookpro/

Comment: There's also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter) with a fix for that error.